# Making jelly using erythritol & monk fruit extract in place of sugar

Tags: substitutions, food-preservation, sugar

I'm making jelly. The box of pectin says not to reduce the sugar or it can cause 'set failure'. I want to use 'erythritol w/ monk fruit extract' in place of sugar (purchased from Costco). Will that effect how my jelly will set b/c it's not regular sugar?

Comment: Sugar in many things is far more fundamental food chemistry than "sweetness" and substitution is difficult-to-impossible.

Comment: You chose the tag "food-preservation". Note that if you substitute the sugar, the recipe will no longer be safe for canning. You can still cook it, but its official shelf life will be 3-5 days in the fridge.

Comment: To rumtscho, I just bought some Sure-Jell pectin (for reduced-sugar). So is that just for making the jelly 'set'? It has nothing to do with shelf life? Does that mean it is now what they call a freezer jam?

Comment: @JennyKee sugar is part of what preserves a jam, and if you used some sweetener other than sugar for a recipe that calls for sugar, you can't know if it is still safe. You can find a recipe meant for canning that uses your desired sweetener, but it may need extra acid or canning at higher temperatures in order to be safe to store.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, the instructions are pretty clear about that. If you want to make a reduced-sugar jelly, you’ll need to use a modified pectin which is designed for reduced-sugar jelly.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't even aware there is pectin specifically for reduced-sugar jellies.